# Pick from return type by using function parameters

Tags: typescript, graphql

I'm working with Graphql and Typescript and I'd like to tell my functions what data I want returned from a request and for Typescript to know what those types are.

This is my code:

```
// This was auto-generated by my schema builder, I cannot modify it or change its shape
type User = {
    id: string;
    name: string | null;
    email: string | null;
    emailVerified: Date | null;
    image: string | null;
    role: Role;
}

export const getUsers= (
  params: (keyof User)[]
): Pick<User, typeof params[0]>[] => {
  // graphql request here
}
```

This compiles and allows me to *only* pass parameters that exist in the `User` type, however I can't seem to get Typescript to `Pick` just the types I've passed as arguments.

For example:

```
const users = getUsers(['id']);

// This won't error
console.log(users.name)
```

I assume this is because I'm doing `typeof params[0]`, so it's just checking the type and not the strings that are passed as parameters.

Is this even possible with Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a generic type to the function:

```
export const getUsers = <K extends (keyof User)[]>(
  params: [...K]
): Pick<User, K[number]>[] => {
  return {} as any
}
```

`K` will hold the type information of the tuple you pass to the function. By using `K[number]` we get a union of all elements in the tuple which we can use for `Pick`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdQO4EN5IK4BcD2BaA5gKYB2BATkhgQCagBGAnqALaOwDGkBTSda0ANlTIAaUAElQbJESJYMzLFWgAzRtHlZSkyNMKh18WDoAOBAFAZ6p0AFVYZUAF5QAbzOgP%20qgC5QsDKTQRHgA3O6eREhMBL7%20gcGgAD6gRGj8-GGeoFxIArEBQXhJKWkZ4R45AgBqZCrQ1L4AIhQExanpmZ7Q3IT58UXJ7WVZpFj8MX4FwWEAvmZmBAAexprybFhE-qCEGHZk8M4APADS2YuURFTwABQA1gT0WMq29qQAlADaALoAfNfhxiQ5CYsF8HwAdJDjl8zG9fAAFaBsW6HPakUTHD6pJi0Mi-b5OH6ucKkAgYNCkIiuGagFC0oj0MxzebrTbyNCvA7bMlo2DXD4AcmgVAFXzeYTMIAgMHgCA2AvkZFGpDMrNgYwI4P4WDw1w5%203BkWibyAA)

Comment: I would've never figure it out, I'm still learning Typescript generics. Thank you so much!